# Freeradius : virtual server and multiple client with same ip address

Tags: freeradius

This is my first time posting on StackOverflow, and I've only recently started working with FreeRADIUS. Without delving too deep into the specifics of my project, I'm facing challenges in setting up a centralized system that allows access from multiple IP addresses across different virtual servers. Ultimately, I'm getting a "Failed to add duplicate client" error. However, based on the documentation available at this [link](https://networkradius.com/doc/3.0.10/raddb/sites-available/home.html), it seems that FreeRADIUS should support this kind of setup.

To put it schematically, the requirement is as follows:

`-> 1812 -> SITE1 -> access possibility from ipv4addr = 0.0.0.0/0`

`-> 1814 -> SITE2 -> access possibility from ipv4addr = 0.0.0.0/0`

and so on.

I sincerely appreciate any assistance or insights you can provide.

P.S. I've attached the configuration files for reference.

/etc/freeradius/3.0/sites-enabled/default`(https://pastecode.io/s/iamhnz5h)`
/etc/freeradius/3.0/radiusd.conf`(https://pastecode.io/s/p9r4mwtm)`
/etc/freeradius/3.0/clients.conf`(https://pastecode.io/s/79zynd2c)`

I've conducted numerous tests, and despite finding some posts on Google, none of them provide a solution for my specific case. I hope someone can provide an answer.

Comment: this question is better asked at https://superuser.com